# Lightning Layout Alignment Issue

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

LWC lightning-layout with slds Size Attribute not flowing properly on Microsoft Edge and IE.

In Chrome alignment seems to be fine fine.

**In Microsoft edge:** the two div is displaying next,next row.

**In IE:** The right Div getting shrink towards the left.

```
    <lightning-layout vertical-align="left" class="x-large">
        <div class="slds-size_2-of-8">

            <lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item={selectedItem} onselect={handleSelect}
                    class="navigation">

                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
                        <lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon label="Family Name" name="family_name"
                            icon-name="utility:groups">
                        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon>
                    </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
                </lightning-vertical-navigation>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </div>

        <div if:true={showDivlayout} class="slds-size_6-of-8">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">

            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-layout>
```

Comment: Rendering custom lightning components in IE and MS Edge is not great when compared to chrome. I would recommend to get rid of the first div element and move its class attribute to the lighting-layout-item element. Also, replace the other div elements with lightning-layout-item retaining the attributes. Lightning framework would convert this markup into appropriate elements and the base components are generally rendered without any issue or less issues in IE and Edge. Could you give this a try?

Comment: Have you checked that the [browser versions you are using are supported](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Edge did not support custom elements in a flexbox context It's a known issue
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YmXSQA0

Resolution:
you should use a and grid items (with sizes), per the SLDS grid documentation.